# Positive and negative part of a function: prove that $(f(x) -a\,g(x))^+\le b h(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f, g, h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be non negative functions and assume that
$$f(x)\le a\, g(x) + b \, h(x),$$
for some $a, b\in\mathbb R_+$.

Define
$$k(x):=(f(x) -a\,g(x))^+.$$
Here $k^+ = \max\{0, f(x)\}$, as usual.

I am solving an exercise which gives the hint: start proving that $k(x)\le b h(x)$.
But why one can say that $k(x)\le b h(x)$?
I would say that
$$ k^+\le f^+ = f.$$
What am I doing wrong? Is the inequality stated in the hint actually correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)<ag(x).$ Then:
$$k(x) = 0\leq bh(x)$$ as $b,h\geq 0.$
Let $f(x)\geq ag(x).$ Then:
$$k(x) = f(x)-ag(x)\leq bh(x)$$ due to the given hypothesis. So either way,:
$$k(x)\leq bh(x).$$